# Import path difference between running script and running as setuptool generated executable

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools

I have a project which I have reduced to the following demo code structure:

```
[import_error]
    setup.py
    [import_test]
        __init__.py
        import_demo.py
        [common]
            __init__.py
            function.py
```

It uses entry_points in setup.py to create a executable for easy use.
It uploads and installs as it should to/from my private pi server. (devpi)

My problem is that when I run the script as a py file my import path for function.py has to be:

```
from common.function import hello_world
```

But when I run it via the pip install auto generated executable my import path has to be:

```
from import_test.common.function import hello_world
```

What I have tried to do to solve it:

- Lots of googling
- Renaming packages, executable name
- Messing with `__init__.py` files (they are empty)
- Using virtualenv to ensure no issue with old versions etc.
- Adding . in front of import path

Here is my code:

setup.py

```py
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="import_test",
    version='1.0.2',
    author="me",
    author_email="me@demo.com",
    url="www.google.dk",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'import_demo_exe=import_test.import_demo:main'
        ],
    },
)
```

import_demo.py

```py
try:   
    from common.function import hello_world
    print('\n#function.py import does not need project prefix')
except:
    from import_test.common.function import hello_world
    print('\n#function.py import needs project prefix')

def main():
    hello_world()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

function.py

```py
def hello_world():
    print('Hello World!')
```

Output when I run the script from cmd line:

```
>python import_demo.py
>#function.py import does not need project prefix
>Hello World!
```

Output when I run the executable from cmd line after pip install

```
>import_demo_exe
>#function.py import needs project prefix
>Hello World!
```

Does anyone have an idea on how I can fix this so I only need one include path in my script without try/except ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a solution:

```py
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0])
```

Add this to the main python file before any imports.
It will add the path of the main python file to system path and the imports will start working.